# How do I get the current running version of a package in deb file's postinst and preinst script?

Tags: deb, packaging

I am creating a debian package that discard some database operations carried out in `postinst` script of the package if its previous version is installed. I googled and [found it for RPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740254/rpm-build-spec-file-i-want-to-check-rpm-is-being-install-or-update) but I could not find for debian.

I am wondering if there is an equivalent variable or something of `%pre[un]` or `%post[un]` for Debian?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html#details-of-configuration) the postinst script is called with the old version number as second argument:

```
postinst configure most-recently-configured-version
```

So within your postinst, you simply need to check that argument.

And for [`preinst`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html#details-of-unpack-phase-of-installation-or-upgrade):

> 3. Run the preinst of the new package:
>
>    If the package is being upgraded, call:
>
>    ```
>    new-preinst upgrade old-version
>    ```
>
>    [...]
>
>    Otherwise, if the package had some configuration files from a previous version installed (i.e., it is in the “Config-Files” state):
>
>    ```
>    new-preinst install old-version
>    ```
>
>    [...]
>
>    Otherwise (i.e., the package was completely purged):
>
>    ```
>    new-preinst install
>    ```

Comment: Consider the comment `If there is no most recently configured version dpkg will pass a null argument.`. I don't fully understand what it means but I definetely saw postinst called with a null argument in the wild sometimes.